# Change color of an image in android

Tags: android

I wonder if there is a way to change the color of my image on the button easily,
my simple example is like this,

```
CircleButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
```

I have a play audio icon (white) and want to change the icon color to red, like this

```
CircleButton.setImageResource(ColorChange(Red, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
```

What seems to be the easiest way for doing ColorChange() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ColorFilter` to change the `button` image color. Your button should be `ImageButton`

Set the image resource to the `ImageButton`

```
CircleButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
```

And, change the image color when required like this

```
CircleButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.any_color));
```

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)

Comment: Where would getResources() method come from ?